# Can I use the where clause in SQL Server with the derived table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried to use the `where` clause with the derived table but I got an error.

This is the code:

```
select * 
from
    (select 
         p.product_id, p.product_name,
         (select brand_name from production.brands as bb 
          where bb.brand_id = p.brand_id) as [brand name],
         (select category_name from production.categories as c 
          where c.category_id = p.category_id) as [categories name]
     from 
         production.products as p) as newtable
where 
    product_id in (select product_id from newtable where [brand name] = 'Trek')
```

The error that I got is :

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
>   Invalid object name 'newtable'.

Comment: Use a cte instead. `WITH newtable as (select ....)`

Comment: Why would a value for `product_id` in `newtable` not appear in `newtable`?

Comment: @jarlh this means that drived tables are limited to do spacific things only

Comment: In a select, a derived table is "executed" only once, while a cte can be "executed" any number of times. However, I write many more derived tables than cte's.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need to use some proper inner joins. There is no need to use CTE or sub queries, it is a rather straight forward query as far as I can tell you just have to apply the proper join syntax.

```
SELECT  p.product_id,
        p.product_name,
        bb.brand_name,
        c.category_name
FROM    production.products as p
        LEFT OUTER JOIN production.brands bb ON bb.brand_id = p.brand_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN production.categories as c where c.category_id = p.category_id
WHERE bb.[brand_name] = 'Trek'
```

Comment: hi igor think it is like diffrent ways of thinking some one may do it using subquaries and others may do it using subquaries i do it in subquaries because i am studing subquaries

Comment: probably should be LEFT OUTER JOIN on brands and categories to be equivalent to the original

Comment: It's a subquery (not sub quary), @MinaShaker , and a subquery can *only* be referenced by it's outer query, that's it. You can't reference it in another inner query (or an outer outer query). A CTE, however, *can* be referenced in multiple places, including CTEs declared later in the same *statement*.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version using a Common Table Expression (CTE), because conceptually that seems to be what you're trying to do. Because you're referencing newtable twice it needs to be a CTE rather than just an aliased subquery.

```
with newtable as 
(
select p.product_id,p.product_name,(select brand_name from production.brands as bb where bb.brand_id = p.brand_id ) as [brand name],(select category_name from production.categories as c where c.category_id = p.category_id) as [categories name]

from production.products as p

)
select * from
newtable 
where product_id in (select product_id from newtable where [brand name] = 'Trek' )
```